# Web scraping: Expand/contract bounding box depending on results

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, bounding-box

A client wants to know the location of their competitor's stores, so I'm being quasi-evil and scraping the competitor's website.

The server accepts the bounding box (ie, lower-left and upper-right corner coordinates) as parameters, and returns the locations found within the bounding box. This part is working fine, and I can successfully retrieve the store locations given a bounding box.

The problem is that *only the first 10 locations within a bounding box* are returned - so in populated areas, a 10 degree bounding box will return too many locations:

[image]

I could just always use a smaller bounding box, but I'm trying to avoid unnecessary hits to the server while ensuring that all stores are returned.

So I need a way to decrease the search rectangle size when 10 stores are found (since there may be more than 10 stores present), and recursively search with a smaller search rectangle size, and then revert to the larger rectangle for the next grid cell.

I've written the function which retrieves stores from the server given a bounding box:

```
stores = checkForStores(<bounding box>)
if len(stores) >= 10:
  # There are too many stores. Search again with a smaller bounding box
else:
  # Everything is good - process these stores
```

but I'm struggling with how to set the appropriate bounding box for the  `checkForStores` function.

I've tried setting up the main grid cells using `for` loops on the latitude and longitude:

```
cellsize = 10
for minLat in range(-40, -10, cellsize):
    for minLng in range(110, 150, cellsize):
        maxLat = minLat + cellsize
        maxLng = minLng + cellsize
```

... but I don't know how to keep searching with a smaller bounding box if 10 stores are found. I also tried using `while` loops, but I can't get either of them to work.

Thanks for any advice or pointers on where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using recursion. Code should be self-explanatory, but here's how it works:
Giving some boundary box, it checks number of stores in it, and if there are more than or equal to 10, then it divides this box into smaller ones and calls itself with each of this new boundary boxes. It does this until less than 10 stores is found. In that case found stores simply saved in the list.

Note: since recursion is used, then there might happen a situation when maximum recursion depth would be exceeded. That's in theory. In your case, even if you would pass 40 000 x 40 000 km boundary box, it would only take 15 steps to reach roughtly 1 x 1 km boundary box with `cell_axis_reduction_factor=2`:

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: math.log(40000, 2)
Out[2]: 15.287712379549449
```

Anyway, in such case you could try to increase `cell_axis_reduction_factor` number.

Also note: in Python, according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names), functions should be lowercase, with underscores, so I renamed `checkForStores` function to `check_for_stores`.

```py
# Save visited boxes. Only for debugging purpose.
visited_boxes = []


def check_for_stores(bounding_box):
    """Function mocking real `ckeck_fo_stores` function by returning
    random list of "stores"
    """
    import random
    randint = random.randint(1, 12)
    print 'Found {} stores for bounding box {}.'.format(randint, bounding_box)
    visited_boxes.append(bounding_box)
    return ['store'] * randint


def split_bounding_box(bounding_box, cell_axis_reduction_factor=2):
    """Returns generator of bounding box coordinates splitted
    from parent `bounding_box`

    :param bounding_box: tuple containing coordinates containing tuples of
          lower-left and upper-right corner coordinates,
          e.g. ((0, 5.2), (20.5, 14.0))
    :param cell_axis_reduction_factor: divide each axis in this param,
                                       in order to produce new box,
                                       meaning that in the end it will
                                       return `cell_axis_reduction_factor`**2 boxes
    :return: generator of bounding box coordinates

    """
    box_lc, box_rc = bounding_box
    box_lc_x, box_lc_y = box_lc
    box_rc_x, box_rc_y = box_rc

    cell_width = (box_rc_x - box_lc_x) / float(cell_axis_reduction_factor)
    cell_height = (box_rc_y - box_lc_y) / float(cell_axis_reduction_factor)

    for x_factor in xrange(cell_axis_reduction_factor):
        lc_x = box_lc_x + cell_width * x_factor
        rc_x = lc_x + cell_width

        for y_factor in xrange(cell_axis_reduction_factor):
            lc_y = box_lc_y + cell_height * y_factor
            rc_y = lc_y + cell_height

            yield ((lc_x, lc_y), (rc_x, rc_y))


def get_stores_in_box(bounding_box, result=None):
    """Returns list of stores found provided `bounding_box`.

    If there are more than or equal to 10 stores found in `bounding_box`,
    recursively splits current `bounding_box` into smaller one and checks
    stores in them.

    :param bounding_box: tuple containing coordinates containing tuples of
          lower-left and upper-right corner coordinates,
          e.g. ((0, 5.2), (20.5, 14.0))
    :param result: list containing found stores, found stores appended here;
                   used for recursive calls
    :return: list with found stores

    """
    if result is None:
        result = []

    print 'Checking for stores...'
    stores = check_for_stores(bounding_box)
    if len(stores) >= 10:
        print 'Stores number is more than or equal 10. Splitting bounding box...'
        for splitted_box_coords in split_bounding_box(bounding_box):
            get_stores_in_box(splitted_box_coords, result)
    else:
        print 'Stores number is less than 10. Saving results.'
        result += stores

    return result


stores = get_stores_in_box(((0, 1), (30, 20)))
print 'Found {} stores in total'.format(len(stores))
print 'Visited boxes: '
print visited_boxes
```

Here is an example of an output:

```
Checking for stores...
Found 10 stores for bounding box ((0, 1), (30, 20)).
Stores number is more than or equal 10. Splitting bounding box...
Checking for stores...
Found 4 stores for bounding box ((0.0, 1.0), (15.0, 10.5)).
Stores number is less than 10. Saving results.
Checking for stores...
Found 4 stores for bounding box ((0.0, 10.5), (15.0, 20.0)).
Stores number is less than 10. Saving results.
Checking for stores...
Found 10 stores for bounding box ((15.0, 1.0), (30.0, 10.5)).
Stores number is more than or equal 10. Splitting bounding box...
Checking for stores...
Found 1 stores for bounding box ((15.0, 1.0), (22.5, 5.75)).
Stores number is less than 10. Saving results.
Checking for stores...
Found 9 stores for bounding box ((15.0, 5.75), (22.5, 10.5)).
Stores number is less than 10. Saving results.
Checking for stores...
Found 4 stores for bounding box ((22.5, 1.0), (30.0, 5.75)).
Stores number is less than 10. Saving results.
Checking for stores...
Found 1 stores for bounding box ((22.5, 5.75), (30.0, 10.5)).
Stores number is less than 10. Saving results.
Checking for stores...
Found 6 stores for bounding box ((15.0, 10.5), (30.0, 20.0)).
Stores number is less than 10. Saving results.
Found 29 stores in total
Visited boxes: 
[
((0, 1), (30, 20)), 
((0.0, 1.0), (15.0, 10.5)), 
((0.0, 10.5), (15.0, 20.0)), 
((15.0, 1.0), (30.0, 10.5)), 
((15.0, 1.0), (22.5, 5.75)), 
((15.0, 5.75), (22.5, 10.5)), 
((22.5, 1.0), (30.0, 5.75)), 
((22.5, 5.75), (30.0, 10.5)), 
((15.0, 10.5), (30.0, 20.0))
]
```

Comment: This is awesome - thanks for taking the time to write it out with such good explanations.